# Give my own app(paid) as gift to some users on google play

Tags: android, layout, adview

I want to launch a paid version of my app and i've some doubts

i've read https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7271135?hl=en&ref_topic=3452890 and I know i can create a sale or even offer my app for free temporarily. But this links tell about creating a discount to anybody, what if I want to create public specific discount? is that possible?

Ex.  if I want to give my app as a gift to friends, relatives can I "list" some google accounts and give my app free to them [so anytime they decide to download they dont need to pay]

Ex2. Can I create some kind of redeem code which anyone with the code can download my app without paying (each redeem code could be used a limited number of times)

I'm would like to offer my app for free to some youtubers to test and review it and i would like to have a better way to delivery it to them than give an apk and ask them to "allow unknow sources"

Answer (score 1):

On the Play Store console for your paid app, you can go to User Acquisition > Promotions and generate a promotion for a free or discounted download. You will get a list of codes you can share with people to let them use that promotion.

They can take that code and go buy the app through the Play Store, and when they click "purchase" on the Play Store to buy the app there is a place for them to enter the code.

It's not a public promotion, the only people who can use it are those who you give the codes to.

You can read more about it [here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6321495?hl=en).